# Save media files to Blackberry SD card

Tags: blackberry, file-io, outputstream, image, ringtone

I am creating a multimedia app that allows the user to save wallpapers and ringtones. I know the path I need to save them to is "SDCard/BlackBerry/ringtones/file.mp3" (or "/pictures" for wallpapers). I have searched forums and post for a couple days and the only thing I found was how to write text files. For now, assume that the ringtones and pictures are saved in the projects resource folder. If you could provide any input, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help cjp. Here is the code to saving a resource mp3 file to a sd card:

```
byte[] audioFile = null;
try {
    Class cl = Class.forName("com.mycompany.myproject.myclass");
    InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("/" + audioClip);
    audioFile = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);

    try {
        // Create folder if not already created
        FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/ringtones/");
        if (!fc.exists())
            fc.mkdir();
        fc.close();

        // Create file
        fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/ringtones/" + audioClip, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        if (!fc.exists())
            fc.create();
        OutputStream outStream = fc.openOutputStream();
        outStream.write(audioFile);
        outStream.close();
        fc.close();

        Dialog.alert("Ringtone saved to BlackBerry SDcard.");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Dialog.alert(ioe.toString());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Dialog.alert(e.toString());
}
```

As cjp pointed out, here is how to save an image resource to a SD card:

```
EncodedImage encImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(file.jpg"); 
byte[] image = encImage.getData();
try {
// create folder as above (just change directory)
// create file as above (just change directory)
} catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 4):

Saving anything should be about the same. Try something like this:

```
    FileConnection fc;

    try {
        String fullFile = usedir + filename;
        fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fullFile, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        if (fc.exists()) {
             Dialog.alert("file exists");
        } else {
            fc.create();
            fileOS = fc.openOutputStream();
            fileOS.write(raw_media_bytes, raw_offset, raw_length);
        }
    } catch (Exception x) {
        Dialog.alert("file save error);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileOS != null) {
                fileOS.close();
            }
            if (fc != null) {
                fc.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception y) {
        }
    }
```

usedir and filename are your path components, raw_media_bytes is your data, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that part of it. But I don't know how to use the write statement with my files. Assume the ringtone and picture is saved in the "res" folder. How do I convert the resource media files to bytes (so I can use the write statement). The images are .jpg and the ringtone is .mp3. Thanks again.

Comment: I figured out how to get a byte[] from an image resource using: EncodedImage encImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(file.jpg"); byte[] image = encImage.getData();     However, I can't figure out how to get my mp3 file to a byte[]. If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure I've done this but this URL says getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename) is your best bet: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Create_BB_app_that_plays_media_from_input_stream_739580_11.jsp